# Subquery with conditional select

Tags: mysql

**EDIT** Trying to list all items which have a quantity greater than that for any other item for the same job

```
Table items
+--------+----------+
| job_id | quantity | 
+--------+----------+
| 004    |      150 |
| 004    |        4 |
| 004    |      100 |
| 002    |       50 |
| 002    |        2 |
| 002    |       17 |
| 002    |       17 |
| 006    |        2 |
+--------+----------+
```

I know it should be a fairly simple one but it's got me stuck. I was trying to use ANY in the query but i wasn't quite sure how to use it. Here's what i'm thinking:

```
select job_id, quantity
from items
where quantity >
    (select min(quantity) from items) group by job_id;
```

I was way off with that one. Thanks for the help

```
select job_id, max(quantity) from po_items group by job_id;
```

That one did the trick

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
select job_id, quantity 
from items 
where quantity > (select MAX(quantity) from items where ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use function `MAX()`

You can  use  `select MAX(quantity) from items where`

```
select job_id, quantity 
from items 
where quantity > (select MAX(quantity) from items where ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

PSR is on  the right path.

For the max value of each job, the aggregate MAX() function can be used, most efficiently with GROUP BY.

Try:

`select job_id, MAX(quantity) 
from items 
GROUP BY job_id`

(sent from mobile)

Answer (score 0):

Without `SUBQUERY`.Check [SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0ad70/1)

```
SELECT
  job_id,
  MAX(quantity)
FROM items
GROUP BY job_id
```